# Vaadin Flow: Numberfield for Integers

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

how does one define a NumberField for VaadinFlow that does not initially start like this:

[image: initial Numberfield (displays 1,0)]

I tried the code below:

```
NumberField numberfield = new NumberField();
numberField.setStep(1d);
numberField.setMin(0d);
numberField.setMax(Long.MAX_VALUE);
numberField.setPreventInvalidInput(true);
numberField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);
numberField.setHasControls(true);
numberField.setPattern("([0-9])+");
```

But all it achieves is that it increments correctly:

[image: incremented number (2)]

Comment: It is true that handling Integers could be better in NumberField, there is proposal of improvement here with ongoing discussion https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-text-field-flow/pull/152

Comment: Something related to this has been adjusted for Vaadin 14, but I'm not entirely sure which way. See https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-text-field-flow/issues/172.